# Intersect points and polygons in shapely

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas

I have some polygons and points that I know overlay which look like this:

[image]

One thing to note is that in the polygon shapefile there can be multiple which overlap and I want to intersect through all of them, thus a single point could potentially return numerous rows in the output.  I have been trying this code:

```
from shapely.geometry import *

import geopandas as gpd
pts = gpd.read_file("/path.shp")
poly = gpd.read_file("/path.shp")

combined = pd.DataFrame()
for key , grp in pts.groupby('id'):
    inter = poly.intersects(grp['geometry']).to_frame()
    combined = combined.append(inter)
```

but the output of `combined` returns `False` for every single instance.  Is there anyway to intersect points and polygons in geopandas or shapely? `id` is just the row indicator for each point.

Comment: What is the desired output you are looking for? A dataframe indicating for each point which of the polygons it intersects?

Comment: Each of the polygons has a `Year` column.  I ultimately want to know what the year is for each point. I can determine this myself though if the correct `True` and `False` intersections occur though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is a "spatial join", where we add information of the second dataframe (the polygons, which have the YEAR information) to the first dataframe (the points) based on their spatial relationship:

```
gpd.sjoin(pts, poly[['YEAR', 'geometry']], how='left', op='intersects')
```

This adds a new column to the `pts` dataframe with the YEAR of the polygon in which the point is located. When a point is located in multiple polygons, that point it row will be repeated with the different values for YEAR

---

Additional note on why your approach gave all False values:
In `inter = poly.intersects(grp['geometry'])`, geopandas will check for each polygon in `poly` if it intersects the specified geometry, *if* the specified geometry is a single scalar geometry. However `grp['geometry']` is (as far as I can see from the code) not a scalar value. In such a case, `poly` and `grp['geometry']` are aligned on their index, and then the `intersects` operation is done element-wise (polygon 1 with point 1, polygon 2 with point 2, etc). This is not what you want in this case.

Comment: Yes I was looking for this exactly and thought it was weird to loop through each row.  Not sure if you contribute to geopandas or not but I find the package immensely useful